# Error uploading csv file on Shiny App hosted on AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny

I have a `Shiny App` deployed on `AWS`, on an `EC2 instance`. When I run it locally I can upload files without any issues. But if deployed online when trying to upload a fairly large file (30MB) it does not even tries to upload and I get a red bar in the progress bar labeled "error".

This seems to happen for files larger than 10MB. In my `Shiny App` I have the line:

```r
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
```

So I would assume I should be able to upload files up to 100 MB, but I have not being able to do it. Any ideas? Has anyone experienced the same issue?